# Sequence number generation in odoo

Tags: odoo-11

I am using this code for sequence generation

class cardInfo(models.Model):

```
_name = "library.card"
card_number = fields.Char(String = "Card Number" , size = 7, Translate = True, readonly = True)
user_name = fields.Many2one('student.student',String = "Name")
card_type = fields.Selection([('s', 'Student'), ('l', 'Staff')] , String = "Card Type")
number_of_book_limit = fields.Integer(String = "No Of Book Limit" , default = 0)

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    seq = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('library.card.number') or '/'
    vals['card_number'] = seq
    return super(cardInfo, self).create(vals)
```

but i am getting only the '/' as sequence number.. why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create "ir.sequance" in xml file like,

```
<record id="seq_library_card" model="ir.sequence">
    <field name="name">Library Card</field>
    <field name="code">library.card</field>
    <field name="prefix">LIB</field>
    <field name="padding">5</field>
    <field name="company_id" eval="False" />
</record>
```

In Py file you have to write like,

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        x = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('library.card') or '/'
        vals['card_number'] = x
        return super(LibraryCard, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: I am glad to help you